# how to which person has all the things ? mysql

Tags: mysql

Below is the table

```
person  things
A   TV
A   CAR
A   MOBILE
A   HOUSE
B   TV
C   TV
C   CAR
C   MOBILE
C   HOUSE
D   TV
E   TV
F   TV
```

above I can see that A and C has all the things.

as per book example I was able to find 
WHICH THING EVERY PERSON HAS ? using below query ,

```
SELECT things
FROM tbl_happiness as x 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
( 
SELECT person 
FROM tbl_happiness as y 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
( 
SELECT 1
FROM tbl_happiness as z 
WHERE z.person = y.person 
AND z.things = x.things
 )
);
```

is it possible to use same query with change in alias name , to find

which person has all the things ?

Comment: I was able to find the person names who has everything using below query : SELECT person 
FROM tbl_happiness as x 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS 
( 
SELECT person 
FROM tbl_happiness as y 
WHERE NOT  EXISTS 
( 
SELECT *
FROM tbl_happiness as z 
WHERE z.things = y.things 
AND z.person = x.person
 )
);  I want to display as one person and then the things he has, one name with things he own. how to change this query ?

Answer (score 2):

I approach these "set-within-sets" queries using `group by` and `having`:

```
select person
from table t
group by person
having count(distinct thing) = (select count(distinct thing) from table t);
```

If there are no duplicates, you can use:

```
having count(*) = (select count(distinct thing) from table t);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT person 
FROM tbl_happiness 
group by person
having count(distinct things) = (select count(distinct things) from tbl_happiness)
```

Answer (score 0):

Less efficient perhaps, but nice to look at...

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM my_table x
  LEFT
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT DISTINCT a.person 
                  FROM my_table a 
                  JOIN my_table b 
                  LEFT 
                  JOIN my_table c 
                    ON c.person = a.person 
                   AND c.thing = b.thing 
                 WHERE c.person IS NULL
     ) y
    ON y.person = x.person
 WHERE y.person IS NULL;
```